# Functions keeps returning the same value

Tags: c++, vector

I have really weird problem with my function. I am trying to loop through the vector with a type of my struct `vector<address>` which is built from `x` and `y`. The size is always known, nothing is being erased. What I am trying to do is with given `x` and `y` the function should return me the index on which element of vector those values are stored.

```
struct address {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int n;
    address(int ax, int ay, int an): x(ax), y(ay), n(an) {}
};
```

Function to look for an index looks like:

```
int find_box(vector<address> v, int x, int y, int j) {
    int xc = x;
    int yc = y;
    if(v[j].x == xc && v[j].y == yc) {
        return j;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am invoking function:

```
for(int j = 0; j<vectorBoxes.size(); j++) {
    jot = find_box(temp->box,temp->player->x + MX[i],temp->player->y + MY[i], j);
}
```

Before looping I know that `temp->player->x + MX[i]` = 4 and `temp->player->y + MY[i]` = 3.
I also know that the first element [0] of `temp->box` is equal to: `x = 2` and `y = 3`.
I also know that element third element [2] has values `x = 4` and `y = 3`. So the function should return me 2...

Why is the function returning me 0 in the first loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're continuing to call this find function even after you've potentially found the thing you want. Secondly, `find_box` will return garbage when the if-statement isn't true because you've not specified what it should return.

I'd suggest (NB: as simple fixes for this) returning a `bool` from that function instead of a value you already know. And you should always be explicitly returning something anyway, at the moment you'll only return a sensible value when the `if` evaluates to true e.g.

```
bool find_box(vector<address> v, int x, int y, int j) {
    int xc = x;
    int yc = y;
    if(v[j].x == xc && v[j].y == yc) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You should also stop searching once you've found the thing you're looking for, something like:

```
bool found = false;
for(int j = 0; j<vectorBoxes.size() && !found; j++) {
    if(find_box(temp->box,temp->player->x + MX[i],temp->player->y + MY[i], j)) {
        jot = j;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your find_box function will return zero if it doesn't find the element at index j. This means that as you loop through your addresses, jot will always be set to zero unless the very last address happens to be the one you're looking for.

To fix it, you could detect when no match was found, and return a value that indicates this, such as -1. For example, something like this should work:

```
int find_box(vector<address> v, int x, int y, int j) {
    if(v[j].x == x && v[j].y == y) {
        return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

for(int j = 0; j<vectorBoxes.size(); j++) {
    int tmp_jot = find_box(temp->box,temp->player->x + MX[i],temp->player->y + MY[i], j);
    if (tmp_jot >= 0) { 
        jot = tmp_jot; 
        break; 
    }
}
```

The break statement is just for efficiency, it'll stop the for loop as soon as it finds a match. It will work without it. This code could be made a lot neater, but I didn't want to completely change your logic.

As another example, your find_box function could be changed to actually perform the search and return the index:

```
int find_box(vector<address> v, int x, int y) {
    for(int j = 0; j<v.size(); j++) {
        if(v[j].x == x && v[j].y == y) {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

jot = find_box(vectorBoxes, temp->player->x + MX[i], temp->player->y + MY[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add default return value to check if it failed or not

```
int find_box(vector<address> v, int x, int y, int j) {
    int xc = x;
    int yc = y;
    if(v[j].x == xc && v[j].y == yc) {
        return j;
    }
    return -1; // a value which you can check and ignore
}
```

Your problam is vectorBoxes.size() can be more than 3. So even if you find the value 2 in the next iteration your function will return void which is something you don't want.

```
myrealvalue = 0;
for(int j = 0; j<vectorBoxes.size(); j++) {
jot = find_box(temp->box,temp->player->x + MX[i],temp->player->y + MY[i], j);
if(jot == -1)
     continue;
else{
    myrealvalue = jot;
    break;
}
}    

//access real value
```